# Is there any free tools that allow my non unicode chinese to unicode chinese?

Tags: windows-7, mp3, language, unicode, tags

I have a bunch of chinese songs and the meta tags are written in like non-unicode chinese. It displays on my computer but only if I set the non-unicode locale to chinese.

Is there a free program which can convert non-unicode chinese to unicode chinese? Preferably one that is able to go through all the songs in my library and automatically convert them?

Answer (score 0):

[EasyTAG](http://easytag.sourceforge.net/) allows selection of a single non-standard charset for reading, and default selections for reading and writing; a simple retag should fix them.

Comment: i just d/l and tried to install it. it doesn't work - missing an assembly or something. it's an old app so it probably doesn't work for windows 7

Comment: It's written in C++. I doubt it's missing an assembly.

Comment: im only going by the error msg im getting after i try to run it